# .updateOne isn't updating my MongoDB in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

I'm trying to change a user token within my MongoDB using .updateOne and although the user item is returned correctly, there is still no update to the value I am trying to change.

What I am trying to do is log a user in, if they exist, and set an API_Key to be used for validation in a GET request. The main issue I am having is updating the new API key within the specified user.

```
app.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password, is_team_driver_login } = req.body
    const EPK = req.headers['epk']

    if(EPK !== process.env.EPK){
        return res.status(401).json({message : `Error 401 : Missing or invalid API key`})
    }

    Users.findOne({ username: {$regex: new RegExp(username, 'i') } }).then((user) => {
        if(!user){
            console.log('User not found')
            return res.status(401).json({message : `User ${username} not found`})
        }
        
        if(user.password !== password) {
            console.log(`Incorrect Password for user ${username}`)
            return res.status(401).json({message : `Password incorrect`})
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({username: user.username}, process.env.SECRET_TOKEN)
        Users.updateOne( {"_id": req.body._id}, {
            $set : {
                "api_token": token
            }
        }).then ((obj) => {
            console.log(obj)
        })
        console.log(user + '\n' + token)
        return res.status(200).json(user)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).json({message : `Bad request`})
    })
})
```

No errors are being returned to me, and the values that I am receiving from the console are as follows:

The user -

```
{
    "menu": {
        "menu_items": []
    },
    "dashboard": {
        "dashboard_items": []
    },
    "full_name": "Gandalf the Grey",
    "api_token": "tk002",
    "username": "GandalfG",
    "password": "UShalNotGuess!"
}
```

The value of the token-
RANDOM_HEX_VALUE

And the obj to verify in my log that there was an update -

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

api_token within my user schema should be updated to the RANDOM_HEX_VALUE that is generated from jwt, however it stays the same.

Comment: The handler completes before the async DB operation does.

Comment: Move `console.log(user + '\n' + token);  return res.status(200).json(user)` inside the `.then((obj) => { console.log(obj) })` block.

Comment: req.body._id is probably a string, is the _id in the database also a string?

Comment: @jQueeny With your fix and a little restructuring of code I was able to get this working. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Using `then().catch()` blocks can lead to this kind of thing quite often so I would recommenced you adopt the `async/await` pattern utilising `try/catch` blocks. It allows you to write code without worrying about which `then()` block you are in .